# How do I get two different type of values from database in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

want to get id and a value stored against it.
value is in float.
i m trying to sort the value and then show it according to the corresponding id.

```
public List GetStuCosineSimilarity()
{
    Dictionary data = new Dictionary<int,>();
    List stuId = new List();    

    data = (from s in DB.Students
            select new
            {
                id = s.StudentId,
                cosine = s.cosineSimilarity
            }).ToList();

    return stuId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, try this:

```
// data is your dictionary with id and value
var data = DB.Students.ToDictionary(s => s.StudentId, s => s.cosuneSimilarity);
```

Then, if you need to return the list of IDs you can do this:

```
return data.Keys.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? Cosine { get; set; }
}

public List<student> GetStuCosineSimilarity()
{ 
    List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();

    lst = (from s in DB.Students
           select new Student()
           {
               Id = s.StudentId,
               Cosine = s.cosineSimilarity
           }).ToList();

    lst = lst.OrderBy(k => k.Cosine).ToList(); // Sorting the float value
    return lst;
}
```